# Changing the implementation of Objective C method in Swift subclass

Tags: objective-c, swift

I am using an external library in my project. It is integrated via CocoaPods. I have access to the source code. The library is working well, but I need some modifications at some places in order for it to serve my purposes. It is written in Objective C. My project is in Swift. 
I need to change the implementation of one method in the library. The problem is it is in the .m file and uses a lot of stuff declared only in the .m file. For example:

```
-(NSString*)methodToChange
{
    NSArray<NSNumber*>* data = [self someInternalMethod:1];
    uint value = data[0].unsignedIntValue;
    return [self anotherInternalMethod:value];
}
```

I tried subclassing it like this:

```
class MySubclass : MySuperclassWithMethodToChange {
    override var methodToChange: String {
        //trying to use someInternalMethod and anotherInternalMethod
        //unsuccessfully because they are not visible 
    }
}
```

The internal methods are using and modifying properties from the .m file that are also not accessible. Is there any way to solve this?

Comment: Move their declaration into the header file so Swift can see the method?

Comment: @trojanfoe Wouldn't that mean changes to the library source code?

Comment: Yes it would...

Comment: You could also fork the library, make the necessary changes in your fork and have your Podfile point to your fork. If your changes could be useful to others, make them in a way that doesn't break existing functionality and contribute them back to the library by opening a pull request.

Comment: Absolutely correct.

Comment: @Gereon Thank you, this will probably be the way to go. One question since I have not done this - what happens when the original library has updates I want. Will that work if I have forked the library and pointed to the fork.

Comment: You will have to merge those changes from the so-called "upstream" repository into yours. This does not happen automatically, so you'll have full control (and responsibility) over that process. See https://help.github.com/en/articles/syncing-a-fork for how this would look like.

Comment: @Gereon Thanks a lot! If you post your answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest forking the original library repository and making the necessary changes in your fork. You can then have your Podfile point to that. If your changes could be useful to others, make them in a way that doesn't break existing functionality and contribute them back to the library by opening a pull request.

If the original library gets updated later, you will have to merge those changes from the so-called "upstream" repository into yours. This does not happen automatically, so you'll have full control (and responsibility) over that process. See https://help.github.com/en/articles/syncing-a-fork for how this would look like.